# OpenGL: GL_CLAMP causing Invalid Enum error

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm using the LWJGL, and the following OpenGL call causes an Invalid Enum error when checked with Util.checkGLError()

GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_CLAMP);

I've narrowed it down to the GL_CLAMP, since GL_REPEAT Works. It should also be noted that GL_CLAMP works fine on my laptop, but the error comes in when I'm running it on my desktop. The desktop has a Raedon 5700. Is this a known driver issue or something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it was on an older version of opengl|es but maybe its similar to this case. I remembered there were some kind of limitation with GL_CLAMP and i think it has something to do with the texture must be power of 2. Again this is just a wild guess and maybe something to try out.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the OpenGL Manual Pages? http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: stop using `GL_CLAMP`. What you really want is [`GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Edge_value_sampling) anyway. `GL_CLAMP` doesn't do what you think it does.

If you've somehow created a core OpenGL context with LWJGL, then that's probably why you're getting `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. Because `GL_CLAMP` was removed from core OpenGL back in 3.1.

Comment: Question: Is the number "3.1" meaning "OpenGL 3.1" or "Windows 3.1"?

Comment: @tom_mai78101: I didn't say anything about Windows, so it's perfectly clear from the context that I'm talking about OpenGL and not Windows.

Comment: WHAT? I guess I need to catch up... I've been staying in 1.X and 2.X for so long.